# Conversion from HTML to pdf generates an exception

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

I have a small C# desktop application that creates a pdf file given some HTML, retrieved from an *.eml file. 
Here is a sample:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <div style="font: normal 13px Arial; color:#000000;">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt"><font size="3"><font face="Calibri">Some text<o:p></o:p></font></font><br />
  </p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt"><o:p><font size="3" face="Calibri">&nbsp;</font></o:p><br />
   <span style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: &quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-ansi-language: IT; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA">Some other text</span>
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works just fine on my machine (Win10 x64), however when I run the same code on the client's machine (Win Server 2008 R2 x64), I get the "document has no pages" message from an iTextsharp exception.

This only happens sometimes, for specific HTML strings like the one I just posted; I can't run a debugging session on the client's machine, however I verified that the program receives well formed HTML (as it is parsed with the HTML Agility Pack).

Can this be a font-related issue? I have absolutely no clue, these seem to be present on the client's machine.

Here is a snippet of the code I use to create the pdf document (it uses a custom image tag processor, though it should not be the issue since there isn't any in the given snippet):

```
using (var document = new Document())
{
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create));
    writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
    document.Open();

    var tagProcessors = (DefaultTagProcessorFactory)Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
    tagProcessors.RemoveProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG);
    tagProcessors.AddProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG, new CustomImageTagProcessor());
    CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
    cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS());
    var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
    cssResolver.AddCss(@"code { padding: 2px 4px; }", "utf-8", true);
    var charset = Encoding.UTF8;
    var hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider()));
    hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(true).AutoBookmark(true).SetTagFactory(tagProcessors);
    var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer));                            
    var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
    var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
    var xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, charset);
    xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(fixedMarkup));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. As I suspected, it was related to the font.

On my machine, Calibri font can be embedded in the *.pdf document, while on the other machines its "Font embeddability" property is set to "Restricted".

I guess I'll have to parse the HTML and change all the values inside "font family" tags into a non-restricted one.

Answer (score 1):

You should migrate to pdfHTML, the iText7 (latest version of iText) add-on that converts HTML to PDF.
A lot of bugs (related to tables, fonts and layout in general) were fixed over the years, so by default it's more likely that pdfHTML is able to do the conversion.

sample code:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
    "<b>This text should be written in bold.</b>", 
    new PdfWriter(new File("C://users/mentre83/output.pdf")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to get a trial license to verify whether this is a better solution. I'd still like to determine the causes of the different behavior on the two machines.

Comment: I think (but this is based more on experience than on actually running your code) it will probably have to do something with fonts, or other resources that are not available on one computer, but are available on the other. For instance, if a glyph can not be rendered (because the font does not have that glyph) iText will simply not render that character. If all of your characters are skipped, no content is added and you get the "document has no pages" exception. And Arial unicode is not available on all machines.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Although glyphs don't seem to be the issue, I suspect this has something to do with fonts. Resources-wise, the machines I used to test the code (I tried it on a few VMs too) seem to be pretty much identical.